# How to create tiled map?

Tags: javafx-2

How to create a tile based game map in javafx 2.0?

Should I use ImageView elements or there is other method for direct images drawing?

Comment: Can you give more details, please? Tile games range from checkers to Sid Meier's Civilization...

Comment: @SergeyGrinev Thanks for response. I'm creating a map containing rectangular tiles with several layers (terrain layer, units layer, etc..). Something like checkers, but more complicated graphics :-)

Comment: @fxuser May i use your code for my similar problem? Can you please email it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very specific.

As I understand your issue a possible option is to extend a [javafx.scene.layout.Region](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html). So you are free to add other nodes, make some custom drawings, style with css etc. Nearly everything is possible :)

**Example Code (Sorry, no SSCCE)**

```
public class Tile extends Region {
    public Tile() {
        //add custom creation code
    }

    //add all required methods for custom drawing, styling etc.
}
```

Tiles can be placed inside a e.g. TileContainer (another Object extending e.g. a Region) at a specified position (described by x/y-coordinates).

```
public class TileContainer extends Region {
    private void addTiles() {
        //create your tiles e.g. like this
        double xPositon = 10; //example value
        double yPosition = 20; //example value

        Tile tile = new Tile();
        tile.setLayoutX(xPosition);
        tile.setLayoutY(yPOsition);

        this.getChildren.add(tile);
    }
}
```

Hope, it helps realizing your ideas.